# Query withTrash, soft delete laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

Basically I manage to get my soft delete working on my User table., problem is now my other pages would not work, I believe I need to make some changes using the withTrashed to the queries for the pages? For example the controller as shown below, how do I add the users column which have been soft deleted, can someone guide me and help me with this?

Controller.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Zone;
use App\Parameter;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $zones = Zone::all();
        $parameters = Parameter::all();

        return view('dashboard', compact('zones', 'parameters'));
    }
}
```

Comment: See this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45669204/1838205

Answer (score 10):

You can just add `->withTrashed()` to your query and use `get` instead of `all`. Like so:

```
$zones = Zone::all(); //Excludes soft deleted

$allparameters = Parameter::withTrashed()->get(); //Includes soft deleted

$allusers = User::withTrashed()->get();
```

Also, `onlyTrashed()` will do what it suggests:

```
$trashedusers = User::onlyTrashed()->get(); //Only soft deleted users
```