# Soft Delete all records from a table in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, model, controller

Is there any way to soft delete all the existing rows in a table?
I have tried ( Prospect::delete(); ) it deleted all the rows permanently, But it doesn't work in soft deleting.

Comment: add a column `isDeleted` and set it  `true`

Comment: As juergen said, by far the easiest way I think. Also I'm confused... never read that much about soft delete, and today its around the 5th question about soft delete in laravel ô.o

Comment: juergen d, can you explain?

Comment: @Moiz He simply means that you should add a `isDeleted` column in your database. Then, when you want to `soft delete` something, you simply set this field to true, otherwise its false. Then in your frontend, simply only display all results `where isDeleted = false`

Comment: Thankyou  @Twinfriends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Laravel framework older than 4.2, then you can set the soft delete in your model as,

```
class ModelName extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'table_name';
    protected $softDelete = true;
}
```

If you are using Laravel framework 4.2, then you can set the soft delete in your model as,

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;
class ModelName extends Eloquent {
    use SoftDeletingTrait;
    protected $table = 'table_name';
}
```

If you are using Laravel framework above 4.2, then you can set the soft delete in your model as,

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class ModelName extends Eloquent {
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'table_name';
}
```

I hope you are using Laravel 5. So you can use the third method.

Answer (score 0):

look at this [soft delete](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#soft-deleting)

use this trait in your model :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
```

and add this to your model and database schema :

**model:**

```
class Flight extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

**database schema**

```
Schema::table('flights', function ($table) {
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

Now, when you call the delete method on the model, the deleted_at column will be set to the current date and time. And, when querying a model that uses soft deletes, the soft deleted models will automatically be excluded from all query results.

To determine if a given model instance has been soft deleted, use the trashed method:

```
if ($flight->trashed()) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It usually not delete rows in database.You should add a column isActive etc. and set it (1/0) or (true/false).
if you want show rows,you should "Select * from table Where isActive=1"